# Как перевести jquery на javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
       var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            paginationClickable: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            parallax: false,
            loop: true,
            height: 'auto',
            paginationClickable: true,
            effect: 'slide',
            disableDraggable: true,
        
            on: {
                init: function (swiper) {
                    getSwiperActiveSlideNumber(swiper);
                },
                slideChange: function (swiper) {
                    getSwiperActiveSlideNumber(swiper);
                }
            },
        })
     $('.thumbs-slide').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        swiper.slideTo($(this).index()); })
    
     function getSwiperActiveSlideNumber(swiper) {
    
    }
```

---

Спасибо за столь обширный ответ. Я извиняюсь, но я забыл пояснить, что класс (.thumbs-slide) выступает в роли буллетов для слайдера.

Вот пример на jquery:

https://codepen.io/CreativeSeo33/pen/ERmZaB

Получается нужно перевести эту строчку `swiper.slideTo($(this).index());`

Comment: Нельзя банан превратить в морковку, даже если они внешне похожи по форме. `jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library.`

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Вам нужно использовать `Swiper` без `$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно перевести эту часть кода на чистый JS

```
$('.thumbs-slide').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        swiper.slideTo($(this).index()); })
```

То мы должны сперва понять что тут происходит:

1. находятся все ноды с классом `thumbs-slide`
2. навешивается обработчик события `клик` с функцией которая предотвращает поведение элемента по умолчанию
3. вызывается метод swiper который делает текущим слайд на который кликнули через его позицию среди других слайдов

Навешивание события `addEventListener` вероятно безболезненно можно заменить описыванием события `onclick`:

```
// находим все ноды thumbs-slide и для каждой ноды
document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs-slide').forEach(node => {
  // определяем событие клика 
  node.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault() // предотвращаем действие по-умолчанию
    const element = event.target // элемент на котором был клик
    // находим его порядковый номер
    const index = Array.from(element.parentNode.children)
      .findIndex(e => e === element)
    swiper.slideTo(index) 
  } 
})
```

Или с `addEventListener` :

```
function clickOnSlide(event){
  const element = event.target
  const index = Array.from(element.parentNode.children).findIndex(e => e === element)
  swiper.slideTo(index)
} 

document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs-slide').forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', clickOnSlide, false)
})
```

При необходимости нужно не забыть отписаться от обработчиков события:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs-slide').forEach(node => {
  node.removeEventListener('click', clickOnSlide)
})
```

Демо:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs-slide').forEach(node => {
  // определяем событие клика 
  node.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault() // предотвращаем действие по-умолчанию
    const element = event.target // элемент на котором был клик
    // находим его порядковый номер
    const index = Array.from(element.parentNode.children)
      .findIndex(e => e === element)
    console.clear()
    console.log(`swiper.slideTo(${index})`) 
  } 
})
```

```css
.thumbs-slide {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<p>Клик на слайд выведет в консоль команду slideTo</p>

<div class="thumbs-slide">слайд 1</div>
<div class="thumbs-slide">слайд 2</div>
<div class="thumbs-slide">слайд 3</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь обширный ответ. Я извиняюсь, но я забыл пояснить, что класс (.thumbs-slide) выступает в роли буллетов для слайдера.

Вот пример на jquery:

https://codepen.io/CreativeSeo33/pen/ERmZaB

Получается нужно перевести эту строчку swiper.slideTo($(this).index());

Comment: @AlexB я посмотрел [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/CreativeSeo33/pen/ERmZaB) но там булеты не отрабатывают на клик, поэтому хотел бы понять точнее задачу. Я вижу что клик работает на всем что лежит в `<div class="thumbs">` т.е. в миниатюрах

Comment: По дизайну макета нужно что-бы при клике на div (в моем случае это div с классом thumbs-slide) прокручивало слайд. Что-бы мои дивы с классом thumbs-slide работали как булеты, при клике на первый-крутило к первому слайду, при клике на второй- ко второму слайду и т.д. В вопрос я добавил скриншот из макета.

Comment: По дизайну совсем другое вижу, т.е нужно чтобы при клике на часть слайда он становился в центр?

Comment: Чтобы при клике на первую с svg иконку-слайд прокрутило на первый, при клике на вторую svg- крутило ко второму слайду. По макету задуманно, чтобы svg иконки работали как булеты. По самим слайдам кликать не нужно.

Comment: Ну вот у вас будет где-то список с иконками (рекомендую ul) задайте этот (или другой) класс каждому li и код будет работать